# How is the memory allocation?

Tags: android, memory-management

I have an `ImageView myImageView` which I create programmatically and that I recreate every moment.

I have this program

```
int size ;
// initialise size
for(int i = 0 ; i<size ; i++){
     myImageView = new ImageViewFind(mapActivity.this.getApplicationContext());
}
```

If `size = 10` , at the end of `for` loop how much memory is occupied? Is it just the last `myImageView` or **ten times** that space? I mean when I reallocate the memory space for `myImageView` did I recover the previous one?

Comment: It's based on the garbage collector. I will be between 1 or 10. U always have the memory allocated for the last, however if the garbage collector ran before the 10th allocation, it will free the previous 9.

Comment: @Sipka how to run the garbage collector?

Comment: you can not force the garbace collector, but you can use [`System.gc()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc()) to **suggest** him to run. But this could result in many errors

Comment: You shouldn't run the garbage collector manually. The garbage collector manages memory operations such as freeing and allocation, automatically.

Comment: @Mindsonic I am working in Android OS

Comment: @RiadSaadi I know, Its the way, how you run the garbage collector on your JVM or DalvikVM.

Comment: @Mindsonic, please I just want an answer to submit, I want to close this question. Can you write an answer